# Merge tags [buildpath] and [build-path]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Both tags refer to eclipse build path; [build-path](/questions/tagged/build-path) (13 questions) should be made a synonym of [buildpath](/questions/tagged/buildpath) (100+ questions).